# javascript appendChild multiple elements

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with `appendChild`. in the code below , i am trying to add multiple button elements to the div with looping , but i get only one button . I know how `appendChild` works . In developers.mozilla it is said , that if element already exists , it is removed from its parent and is set anew . So this is the reason i cant add multiple amount of same elements (button) to the node .

So here is my question , what is the optimal and best way to make it happen ?

```js
function Slide() {
    this.currentStep = 0;
    this.time = 2000;
    this.images = [];

    this.images[0] = 'images/image1.jpg';
    this.images[1] = 'images/image2.jpg';
    this.images[2] = 'images/image3.jpg';
    this.images[3] = 'images/image4.jpg';
    this.images[4] = 'images/image5.jpg';

    let imagesCount = this.images.length;
    let indicatorContainer = document.createElement('div');
        indicatorContainer.classList.add('slide-indicator');
    let buttonIndicator = document.createElement('button');
        buttonIndicator.classList.add('button-indicator');
        buttonIndicator.setAttribute('type', 'button');

    for (let i = 0; i < imagesCount; i+=1) {
        indicatorContainer.appendChild(buttonIndicator);
    }

    document.querySelector('.slide').appendChild(indicatorContainer);
}

Slide.prototype.carousel = function() {     // arrow function-ov chi ashxatum ...uxxel
    document.querySelector('.image').src = this.images[this.currentStep];

    this.currentStep < this.images.length - 1 ? this.currentStep += 1 : this.currentStep = 0;

    setTimeout(this.carousel.bind(imageSlide), this.time);
};



const imageSlide = new Slide();
imageSlide.carousel();
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="slide">
            <img class="image" src="" width="1000" height="500" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="button prev" type="button">
                previous
                <span class="arrow arrow-prev"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="button next" type="button">
                next
                <span class="arrow arrow-next"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its because you're appending the same `buttonIndicator` in the loop. To make it work you should create new element in each loop iteration

Comment: Move `let buttonIndicator` and associated code inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

In your approach you're assigning the same `buttonIndicator` in each loop iteration and not creating any new ones. What you have to to is to create new button in each loop iteration to make it work the way you want.

So this should work:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < imagesCount; i+=1) {
        let buttonIndicator = document.createElement('button');
        buttonIndicator.classList.add('button-indicator');
        buttonIndicator.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        indicatorContainer.appendChild(buttonIndicator);
    }
```

Also it makes more sense to use `const` instead of `let` as you're not reasigning those variables.

Answer (score -1):

Use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
indicatorContainer.appendChild(buttonIndicator.cloneNode());
```